# How to filter specific diffs in git

Tags: git

I am preparing to merge a branch with git and I want to be able to see if there are any changes other than what I'm expecting.

I'd like to execute:

```
git log -p HEAD..branch-to-merge
```

But I would like to be able to filter out diffs that match a regex.  I have a specific regex for inserts that I want to ignore and a certain regex for deletes I want to ignore.

If I can filter out those diffs, I would expect to see no diffs returned.  If there are diffs returned, then I need to examine them because there's changes I either don't want to merge in or they just look different than I expected.

Does git have a parameter (or two or three) that would allow me to filter out diffs?

Comment: Are you looking for diffs or commits? Log is designed to view commits. Diff is designed to view actual diffs.

Comment: @whoisj "git log -p" shows the diff (patch).  I am specifically using log to get a list of commits between one branch and another and -p to show the code changes (diffs, patches) for each of those commits, and I'd like to filter out the code changes that I'm expecting to see.

Comment: Have you looked at a library like libgit2? This seems like something that might need additional power to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

(edited)
A simple solution is to process commits individually.

For example, the following will iterate over the hashes of recent commits (I tested with just a few commits behind HEAD), and then print the hashes of commits whose diff (it seems `git show` is equivalent to `git log -p` for a given commit.) doesn't contain `nativeLibraries`.

```
$ for f in `git log --pretty="%H" HEAD^^^^^^^^^..HEAD `; do git show $f | ( grep -q nativeLibraries || echo $f) ; done
```

Instead of printing the hashes, you can just show the output of `grep`, or `grep -v` for non-matching lines, or do some other processing.

Comment: I'm specifically looking to filter diiffs outputted by the -p option.  Maybe I need to use porcelain and pipe it through grep or something more involved.  Basically I want a list of each diff for each commit and then filter out the diffs based on a regex so all that's left are the diffs I don't expect.

Comment: Made some edits, this might help more. But I'm still not clear on what you mean by 'each diff for each commit'.